# Additive Subscription in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a list of posts that the user can view in a feed. By default, you can view 10 posts. By scrolling down, in a pageless fashion, the next ten posts are loaded, followed by the next ten, and so on. After a bit of scrolling, you might have loaded 150 posts. This means I am subscribing to the posts collection every time I scroll down another ten posts. I can model this with

```
var limit = 150;
return Posts.find({}, {limit: limit, sort: {timestamp: -1}});
```

While you are doing this, however, other users can be posting as well, which comes automatically into your feed. If 30 new posts were made in the time you were scrolling down, you will now be looking at the 180th post.

```
var new = 30;
var limit = 150 + new;
return Posts.find({}, {limit: limit, sort: {timestamp: -1}});
```

With this model, I would simply track the number of new posts since I started scrolling, and resubscribe constantly as new posts are made and as I scroll, which would be not unlike constantly polling the server for posts and defeating the purposes of Meteor's reactivity.

What options do I have for retrieving new documents from a collection without losing the old ones?

Answer (score 1):

My solutions is similar to Jacob's, but instead you track the time the user loaded the page and send it into the publication:

```
Template.blah.onCreated(function() {
  this.limit = new ReactiveVar(10); // I assume this is getting updated already.
  var loadTime = new Date().getTime();
  this.autorun(function() {
    this.subscribe('mySub', loadTime, this.limit.get());
  });
});
```

Then on your server, get the number of items newer than the loadTime and add them to the passed limit to get your modified limit:

```
Meteor.publish('mySub', function(time, limit) {
  var countOfItemsNewerThanLoadTime = Posts.find({ timestamp: { $gt: time } }).count();
  return Posts.find({}, {limit: limit + countOfItemsNewerThanLoadTime, sort: {timestamp: -1}});
});
```

Comment: I like the idea of tracking the time the user loaded the page and sending it in, but if I'm doing that I shouldn't need to even mess with the limits: I can just use two subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have come up with is to track the timestamp as I scroll, and simply request all posts newer than that. As long as the feed is fed by most recent, this would give me a static subscription to get the posts I need.

```
var oldestTime = 1234567890;
return Posts.find({timestamp: {$gt: oldestTime}}, {sort: {timestamp: -1}});
```

The problem with this setup is that it makes it difficult to keep the infinite scrolling working. Once I've scrolled to the bottom, how much do I add? Ten seconds? An hour? If posts were coming in at a consistent rate I could answer that, but depending on user activity the timing could be very inconsistent indeed.

EDIT: After reading Stephen's post, I think I have the solution

Track the time the user loaded the page, as well as the limit of older posts they should see as they scroll.

```
find: function () { //Posts newer than page load
  var startTime = 1234567890;
  return Posts.find({timestamp: {$lt: startTime}}, {sort: {timestamp: -1}});
},
find: function () { //Posts older than page load
  var startTime = 1234567890;
  var limit = 150;
  Posts.find({timestamp: {$gt: startTime}}, {sort: {timestamp: -1}, limit: limit}); 
}
```

I believe the only real consideration here is that I need to make sure I'm comparing against server time and not client time, as the gap in seconds could skip a document or two.